# Set the center of a UIButton programmatically - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` inside a `UIView`, my `UIButton` has constraints which I set in storyboard. Now, I want to set the center of the `UIButton` at the center of the `UIView`. How will I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try `.center` property like

```
myButton.center = self.view.center
```

You can also specify `x` and `y` If you need.

```
myButton.center.x = self.view.center.x // for horizontal
myButton.center.y = self.view.center.y // for vertical
```

Answer (score 8):

This approach is using Using NSLayoutConstraint where self.cenBut is the IBoutlet for your button.

```
func setupConstraints() {
    let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.cenBut, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.cenBut, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.cenBut, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 22)
    self.cenBut.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addConstraints([centerX, centerY, height])
}
```

In viewDidLoad()

```
self.view.removeConstraints(self.view.constraints)
self.setupConstraints()
```

Comment: I also tried it but it gives me an error, anyways thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in 2 ways:

- `myButton.center = view.center //view is your parentView`
- `myButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true`
  `myButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true`

Answer (score 1):

since you are using constraints, you won't be able to set the center so you need to use constraints to set the center as well:

```
    let centerYCon = NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelMessage,
        attribute: .CenterY,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: contentView,
        attribute: .CenterY,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0);
    contentView.addConstraint(centerYCon);


    let centerXCon = NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelMessage,
        attribute: .CenterX,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: contentView,
        attribute: .CenterX,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0);
    contentView.addConstraint(centerXCon);
```

I'm assuming that you know what "programmatically" means with autolayout constraints. If you are truly using autolayout then you must have set the properties of your button to setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false.

Comment: thanks, how will i set the setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false?

Comment: and you set it like this:   self.tableView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

Comment: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal.

Comment: but obviously changing the "tableView" to your ui element

Comment: well, yeah, when you ask to set a view programmatically then you have an issue when the view doesn't exist in a state where you can set constraints.

Comment: im not using a uiview and i want the uibutton in it to be in the center

Comment: so, if you are installing constraints on the UIView then you have to change my answer above from "contentView" to the view you are installing the constratints on, you need to change the "contentView" to the view that contains the button

Comment: well, all I can tell you is that these constraints work but there's something that we are not communicating here. The only thing I can think of is that for some reason your button isn't a subview of the view you are adding a constratint to or the view isn't in the subtree you are working with like the error suggests

Answer (score 0):

I should be

```
yourButton.setCenter(self.view.center);
```

But keep in mind that if you programmatically set the frame of a view, your layout constraints might not work as intended.