# Resetting frame center point for UIButton (with layout constraints) does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

There should be a simple resolution to this problem.  Two UIButtons, Add and Delete.  Delete is optionally hidden.  When both buttons are shown, I wish to locate their centers equidistant from the sides; when only Add is shown, I wish to center it.

Code when both are shown:

```
let x1 = self.view.frame.width / 3
let x2 = 2.0 * x1
self.addBtn.center.x = x2
self.deleteBtn.center.x = x1
self.deleteBtn.isHidden = false
```

Both UIButtons are in my storyboard with top and bottom layout constraints.  When above code is executed, both UIButtons are rendered to the far left of the superview, rather than with the x1/x2 locations above!  When only the Add button is rendered (such that it's center X-axis location is the center of the superview's frame), is too is rendered to the far left!

Something is fishy with layout constraints, I think.  Why would a vertical-only layout constraints impact whether or not a manual reset of the X-axis position of a UIButton works?

Thanks.

Comment: I think I've answered my own question.  See [related article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219161/set-the-center-of-a-uibutton-programmatically-swift).  The idea is that if layout constraints are involved, then you have wire in logic that modifies the constraints to re-position the UIButtons, wherever they lie on the X-axis of superview.

Answer (score 0):

When you use AutoLayout, if you don't provide a complete set of layout constraints the system will guess (usually wrong) and add constraints to give your view a location in it's superview.

With AutoLayout active, changing a view's location is often ignored. Instead, you should add a horizontal constraint, control-drag that constraint into your view controller to create an outlet, and then adjust the constraint's constant value in order to adjust it.

Note that you should be able to create a fixed constraint based on your view's center as a fraction of the superview's center that will "just work", and not need any custom code at all.

I just created a test project and added 2 buttons, both pinned 20 points from the bottom of the superview. I created constraints on both that made the view center the same as the superview's center. I then edited both constraints and made the left one a constraint between the button's center X and the superview's trailing, with a multiplier of 0.33. For the right button, I edited the constraint to again be between the button's center and the superview's trailing, but with a multiplier of 0.66. That automatically spaces the buttons out evenly regardless of the size of the content view. The same approach works for any number of views - you just need to adjust the multiplier for each view to be `(item_index+1) / (num_items + 1)` (for zero-based item indexes)